# How to draw 1 isosceles triangle with vertex facing left side of screen using C++

Tags: c++

I am a student and am looking for a way to solve a problem online with content like the image below [image]

Please solve it for me with C++ code

Comment: Why did you use the tag [tag:C]?

Comment: We're not going to write your homework for you from scratch. Can you show your attempt as code?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's possible to use c instead of c++ which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve such a problem, then you need split the big problem in to smaller problems. Then the solution is easier.

So, let's first strip of the '*'. They are always starting a row and ending it. This is not needed in the beginning.

Next. You see some sequences, like

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
1234321
12321
121
1
```

You see that the digits will be incremented by one until we hit the maximum value for this row and then decremented again until they are 1.

The decreasing numbers are also not important at the moment, because, it is simple to decrement them from the maximum number.

Stripping of the decremented numbers, we will get:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

And this looks like a triangle and can be generated mathematically by a typical [triangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function).

We want to calculate the maximum number in a row from the row value istelf. Applying the algorithm from the triangular function, will always result in a formular with the "abs"-function. So taking the absolute value.

We will then get something like the below:

```
Row     5-abs(Row-5)
 0          0           
 1          1           
 2          2           
 3          3           
 4          4           
 5          5           
 6          4           
 7          3           
 8          2           
 9          1          
 10         0
```

We see also that the number of output lines is double the input value.

We can then do a simple increment/decrement loop, to show the digits according to the before shown values.

Then we add a little bit the output of the "*". Please note, that the "closing" star "*" at the end of the line is not needed in the first and last row.

Having explained all the above, we can now start writing the code. There are really many many potential solutions, and I just show you one of them as an example.

Please have a look and implement your own solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    // Tell user what to do
    std::cout << "\nPlease add number for the triangle: ";
    
    // Get the maximum extent from the user. Limit values
    int maxN{};
    if ((std::cin >> maxN) and (maxN >= 0) and (maxN < 10)) {
        
        // Now we want to print row by row 
        for (int row=0; row <= (maxN * 2); ++row) {
        
            // Calculate the maximum value that should be shown in this row
            int maxValueForRow = maxN - std::abs(row-maxN);
            
            // You may uncomment the following line for getting more info
            //std::cout << maxValueForRow << '\t';
            
            // Always print at least on beginning star
            std::cout << '*';

            // Now we want to print the digits. Start counting with 0
            int i = 0;
            
            // Print and increment digits
            for (i = 0; i < maxValueForRow; ++i) std::cout << i+1;
            // And now decrement the digits and print them
            for (i=i-2; i >= 0; --i) std::cout << i+1;
            
            // Show closing star only, if we are not in first or last row
            if (maxValueForRow > 0) std::cout << '*';
            
            // Start a new line
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Invalid input\n";
}
```